# Access dark versions of .heic image files with Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, image, heic

On MacOS, .heic image files can contain one light and one dark version. This can be seen for system wallpapers using `open`: for example
`open /System/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Dome.heic`

The Preview app displays both versions. My goal is to be able to access them using Objective-C, as I would like to save both light and dark versions to .jpg format.

Following snippet succeeds in extracting the **light** version and saving it to disk:

```
NSString* wallpaper_path = /* insert source path here */;
NSString* converted_path_str = /* insert destination path here */;

NSImage* image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:wallpaper_path] autorelease];
NSData* data = [image TIFFRepresentation];
NSBitmapImageRep* rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:data];
NSDictionary* properties =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
data = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:properties];
[data writeToFile:converted_path_str atomically:NO];
```

However I cannot find how to access the **dark** version using `NSImage`, `NSImageRep` or `NSBitmapImageRep`.
As Preview succeeds in doing it, I think it's possible though. I just don't know how to do.

Comment: What is the value of `image.representations.count`?

Comment: It is 2 for Light and Dark desktop pictures, and 8 for Dynamic desktop ones. Discarding the unwanted representation of L&D pictures before writing to disk solves my issue.

Comment: Why are you converting to TIFF instead of converting the two representations directly to JPEG?